# Select onchange, trying run script to load separate text into 2 textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I have a table and within it is a set of select values which auto populate a textarea based on which of the options is selected. What I am trying to do is make it populate two pieces of information into separate text areas when an option is chosen, The first being text into Bar_green and the second being a URL into Top_green2. Is this possible?  I just can't wrap my brain around this. Here is the code I am using:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<HTA:APPLICATION id="" applicationname="" border="thick" caption="yes" icon="c:\windows\system32\write.exe" showintaskbar="yes" singleinstance="no" sysmenu="yes" windowstate="normal" contextmenu="yes">
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 height="100%" width="100%">
<tr>

<td class="top_area" id="top_green">

<script type="text/javascript">
        function showText_green(){
           var value = document.getElementById('options_green').value;
           if(value != ""){
             document.getElementById('bar_green').innerHTML = value;
             document.getElementById('bar_green').style.display = "block";
           }
        }
    </script>

<!--<script type="text/javascript">
        function showLink_green(){
           var value = document.getElementById('options_green').value;
           if(value != ""){
             document.getElementById('top_green2').innerHTML = value;
             document.getElementById('top_green2').style.display = "block";
           }
        }-->
    </script>
        <select id="options_green" onchange="showText_green(); showLink_green()">
            <option value="">Select an option</option>
            <option value="text 1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="text 2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="text 3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="text 4">Option 4</option>
            <option value="text 5">Option 5</option>
            <option value="text 6">Option 6</option>
            <option value="text 7">Option 7</option>
       </select>

</td>

    <tr>
        <td class="top_area2"><textarea id="top_green2"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
        <td class="bar_area"><textarea id="bar_green"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but one can do it different ways (e.g. - JS and/or jQuery).  Do you want to make the URL clickable or just have it appear in the <textarea> as plain text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with simple JQuery. And for text and URL, you can use custom attributes and `data()` in JQuery. Below is the snippet:.

```js
$("#options_green").on('change', function() {
  $("#top_green2").val($(this).val());
  $("#bar_green").val($(this).find('option:selected').data('url'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 height="100%" width="100%">
  <tr>

    <td class="top_area" id="top_green">

      <select id="options_green">
            <option value="">Select an option</option>
            <option value="text 1" data-url="url-1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="text 2" data-url="url-2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="text 3" data-url="url-3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="text 4" data-url="url-4">Option 4</option>
            <option value="text 5" data-url="url-5">Option 5</option>
            <option value="text 6" data-url="url-6">Option 6</option>
            <option value="text 7" data-url="url-7">Option 7</option>
       </select>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="top_area2"><textarea id="top_green2"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bar_area"><textarea id="bar_green"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Actually this is the biggest part of my issue. I wanted to pull the URLs from the same option and just have 2 values in each option. Like <option value="text value2="url"> But I am beginning to believe that this is not an option

Comment: Well, you can rather have custom attributes. So it should be something like `<option value="TEXT_GOES_HERE" data-url="URL_GOES_HERE">` and in JQuery, you can use `data()` or `attr()` to fetch the value as well as url.

Comment: AHh that may just be what I need. 2 shakes and I will let you know how it goes *crosses fingers*

Comment: Strangely enough it works here but when I try to use the same script in my own code it just does nothing. Both fields end up blank

Comment: Hope you are using correct version of JQuery. Also, check your console for errors.

Comment: You are probably right about this. . I have never used Jquery before (cus I'm old skool) but just by looking at the structure I am wondering why the hell I haven't. I'm just exhausted. I will try again tomorrow. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: I am at it again and still nothing is populating. Both textareas are empty when I select an option. I downloaded Jquery 2.1.1 just for the sake of making sure everything i do is the same and put the Jquery script in but still nothing. Am I putting it in the wrong place maybe?

Comment: Did you check console for errors? And where are you putting JQuery?

Comment: Ugh Finally got it. When I copied It I deleted a Quotation by mistake. Geez. It works perfectly now. Thanks a ton. I'm just shocked it wasn't a comma like it usually is with everything I ever code.

Answer (score 0):

You can populate the url with whatever logic you want

```
var urls = {
    'text 1': 'url 1',
    'text 2': 'url 2'
};

var select = $("#options_green");

select.off("change");
select.on("change", function() {
    $("#bar_green").text($(this).val());
    $("#top_green2").text(urls[$(this).val()]);
});
```